# Prechecked or unchecked components in Inno Setup custom install

Tags: inno-setup

I only need 1 custom installation type with 3 components :

- The first is needed, so checked and readonly.
- The second is optional but part of the default, so checked and writable.
- The third is just optional, so unchecked and writable.

If I don't specify a type explicitly, I don't manage to have components checked by default.

If I specify one, I don't manage to have the last component unchecked as default.

I tried with 2 types but, it has no meaning as it's only one custom installation.
Any idea how to get the expected behavior with a single type?

```
[Types]
Name: "standard"; Description: "Standard installation";
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "first"; Description: "First Component"; Types: standard custom; Flags: fixed 
Name: "second"; Description: "Second Component"; Types: standard custom; 
Name: "third"; Description: "Third Component"; Types: custom;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "Dummy custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "first"; Description: "First Fixed Component"; Types: custom; Flags: fixed 
Name: "second"; Description: "Second Checked Component"; Types: custom 
Name: "third"; Description: "Third Unchecked Component"
```

[image]

Comment: indeed, it does!